# Openframeworks > Dynamically changing(loading) images on daily schedule

Tags: c++, scheduler, openframeworks

As a novice ofx user, loading dynamic media is easy enough, but I have a project where I will need to change- reload different images based on the time of day. Is there an existing addon that might help accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/bakercp/ofxTime to do some basic time calculations or if you have a icalendar-based schedule you can use https://github.com/bakercp/ofxICalendar which will give you ofEvents for each calendar event.  Easier though may be to just use the built-in C++11 time functions (available in openFrameworks 0.9+) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration, etc.  Then it's up to you to create some control logic (if statements, etc) to determine what is currently loaded and what *should* be loaded based on the current time.